Time series regression on mixed frequency overlapping data
I have an hourly univariate time series. I am trying to see if the next hour, day, week etc changes are forecastable from the past changes. The ACF and PACF of the data both look similar and show some significant positive values at lags 3-6. Lag 1 value is negative but not significant. The full sample correlation of hourly changes with daily changes is 0.25, and daily with weekly changes is 0.45 (using overlapping data sampled every hour- so a fair bit of overlap)
I am running 3 sets of regressions:

multiple regression (multiple x)  where
y = future (either hourly or daily or weekly) changes
x = past hourly AND daily AND weekly changes.
Note than the past hourly change information is contained in both the past daily and past weekly changes also

multiple regression where
y = future (either hourly or daily or weekly) changes
x = past changes over horizon equal to or greater than the horizon in y.
So for example if y = daily change, x would only be daily and weekly change, but not hourly.

univariate regression (single x) with various combinations of y and x.


Without looking at the results, is there any obvious issue with any of these regressions?
Separately, since my data is hourly, the data used in the regressions is overlapping-e.g. when y = hourly changes, then the daily changes for every new hour have 23 hours common with the previous y. To account for this overlapping data, I want to use HAC cov, but not sure how many lags to use. I have seen people use lags = no of steps (hours) in the forecast- so 1 when hourly, 24 when daily etc but haven't found any good reason for that. How can I address this issue?

Do you mean multiple or multivariate regression? The former has many x variables, the latter many y variables.

Thanks, I mean multiple (many xs). Edited

There may be overlap between observations of the dependent variable or the regressors.
If the observations of the dependent variable overlap (e.g. $y_t$ and $y_{t-1}$ measure partly the same thing), your effective sample size will be smaller than the nominal one. Then you will need to

either adjust your standard errors as in Hansen & Hodrick (1980) or (probably a better choice) Newey & West (1987), as discussed in this thread);
or model them explicitly using an ARMA structure, i.e. run regression with ARMA errors; the latter can be implemented using, say, auto.arima; see e.g. Bailie et al. "On robust inference in time series regression" (2022) and Diebold's blog posts about the HAC emperor who has no clothes: 1 and 2.

If the observations of the regressors overlap (e.g. $x_{1,t}$ and $x_{1,t-1}$ measure partly the same thing or $x_{1,t}$ and $x_{2,s}$ measure partly the same thing), you are fine. You will have some difficulty of distinguishing between the effects of the different regressors (think of imperfect multicollinearity), but you do not need any special estimation technique or things like that.
